# Laravel Ajax Update 1 Column of record

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a user schedule record that I can update easily without one form field called disabled_dates. disabled_dates is setup to store an array of dates a user can add one at a time. What I did was add a form field with its own button using a javascript function disable() in the onclick attribute to update the record.

```
<div class='input-group text-center'>

{!! Form::text('disabled_dates', null , ['class' => 'form-control text-center datetimepicker15', 'id' => 'disable_date', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}

<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" onclick="disable();" class="btn btn-fab btn-round btn-success">
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </button>
</span>
```

Then created the disable(); like so

```
function disable() {
            var CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
            var disabled_date = document.getElementById('disable_date').value;

            $.ajax({
                type:'PUT',
                url:'/schedule',
                data:{_token:  CSRF_TOKEN, blocked_date: disabled_date},
                success:function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

The controller function used is

```
public function add_blocked_day(Request $request)
    {
        $schedule = User::find(auth()->user()->id)->schedule;
        $current_blocked_dates = $schedule->disabled_dates;
        $schedule->disabled_dates = $current_blocked_dates. ','.$request->blocked_date;
        $schedule->save();
        exit;
    }
```

All Im getting now is too many redirects. The solution Im thinking is to seperate disabled_dates and enclose in its own form tags, because its calling the original form route somehow

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing the function to this

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-day" , function() {
            var CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
            var disabled_date = document.getElementById('disable_date').value;

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'schedule/blocked-day',
                data:{_token:  CSRF_TOKEN, blocked_date: disabled_date},
                success:function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
```